# The 10th Month Is Obviously Teves!

Tags: talmud-gemara, torah-study, megillat-esther, tractate-megillah, 5-megilloth

In [Megilah 13a](https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.13a.20?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) - we bring down a פסוק from the מגילה which says:

“So Esther was taken to King Ahasuerus into his royal house in the tenth month, which is the month Tevet” (Esther 2:16).

Why did the פסוק have to mention "tenth month" & "Teves"?

Couldn't it just have said one!?!?!

These are extra words!!!!!!!

Comment: Is there a particular principle that the megillah can't have extra words as a matter of style or wanting to explain to the listener?  It's not the Torah after all.

Comment: Plenty of other months in tanach are so named לחודש שנים עשר הוא חודש אדר and בחודש הראשון הוא חודש סיון and בחודש השלישי הוא חודש סיון all in the megilla too, but also in (roughly contemporary) zecharia לְעַשְׁתֵּֽי־עָשָׂ֥ר חֹ֙דֶשׁ֙ הוּא־חֹ֣דֶשׁ שְׁבָ֔ט and בְּאַרְבָּעָ֛ה לַחֹ֥דֶשׁ הַתְּשִׁעִ֖י בְּכִסְלֵֽו

Comment: Oh, and as we say: thank you for your question and welcome to the site!

Comment: What does this question have to do with the gemara?

Comment: @Mike its Tanach!!! There are no extra words!!!

Comment: @DoubleAA my question is why in these specific places? Why do we have to mention both phrases by these specific Pesukim???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sefer *Yesha Elohim* asks your question, and brings the answer that it was meant from shamayim that Esther should be taken to Achashverosh in the 10th month because the 10th month is Teves, in which *haguf nehene min haguf* - i.e. that the body has pleasure from the warmth of another body. This concept is brought by the Gemara itself in Megillah 13a, and Rashi there (d"h שהגוף נהנה מן הגוף) explains that the hana'ah is the body heat from another body. So the *Yesha Elohim* is saying that the ribuy of "*הוא חודש טבת*" comes to tell us that Esther was taken specifically in the month of Teves in order to have her find favor in Achashverosh's eyes.

> במסכת מגילה (מגילה יג.) אמר רב חסדא ירח שהגוף נהנה מן הגוף ע״כ הנה שהוקשה לו כי אחר שאמר בחודש העשירי **מאי אתא לאשמועינן שהוא חדש טבת** דזיל קרי בי רב הוא. אלא **בא ללמדנו שמן השמי׳ כוונו שאסתר תלקח בחדש העשירי למה בשביל שהוא חדש טבת ויש טובה והנא׳ בירח זה במה שהגוף נהנה מן הגוף** בו והוא לסיבה שבכל החדשים האחרי׳ ישתנו מזגי וטבעי האנשים כי יש אנשים שטבעם חם או קר ולא יהנו מן הגוף ההפכי לו אדרבא יצרו צעדי אונם אבל בירח הזה אפי׳ שיהיו גופים הפכיים ונגדיים זה לזה נהנים זה מזה כ״ש ירח שהגוף נהנה מן הגוף יר׳ איזה גוף שיהיה:

Meaning To Say: If the pasuk had said just "בחודש העשירי", you would think it just happened to be in the 10th month = Teves, that the pasuk is just telling you when it occurred. The ribuy of "הוא חודש טבת" is to tell you that it wasn't stam that it happened in the 10th month, and to emphasize that the reason for it happening davka in the 10th month is because the month of Teves being a month in which הגוף נהנה מן הגוף.

Comment: that wasn't my question; I knew that. My question was why does it have to mention "10th month" + "Teves?" Couldn't it just have said one?

Comment: What the Yesha Elohim is saying is that if the pasuk had said just "בחודש העשירי", you would think it just happened to be in the 10th month = Teves, that the pasuk is just telling you when it occurred. The ribuy of "הוא חודש טבת" is to tell you that it wasn't stam that it happened in the 10th month, and to emphasize that the reason for it happening davka in the 10th month is because the month of Teves being a month in which הגוף נהנה מן הגוף.

Comment: This is good, you should put it as a final paragraph of your answer intead of in this comment.